# using WebConfigurationManager in unit tests

Tags: asp.net, unit-testing

I'm trying to write some unit tests that test code which alter web.config runtime. To load Web.config, WebConfigurationManager.OpenWebConfiguration is used. This does not work well in Unit tests.

What options do I have? I've tried:

1. Configure the test as an ASP.NET-test with method attributes. This seems brittle because you need to hard code the port on which the development server runs with [UrlToTest("http://localhost:25153/WebSite1")] . I need the test to run on multiple computers configured differently. Also I feel it's overkill to launch an IIS server just to be able to load a text file in a unit test.
2. Load the config from disk using other methods. I've tried configurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(), and I get a Configuration object back, but this doesn't seem to have been parsed correctly. Specifcially the sessionState section under system.web, which is a web-specific setting so that is not very surprising.

Where do I go from here?

Answer (score 0):

What is your end goal in reading the web.config?  Depending on what you are trying to accomplish, there are many different ways to read the web.config.  If you are trying to read the connectionString use:
Imports System.Web.Configuration.WebConfigurationManager
Then in your code use:
Dim cn As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection(ConnectionStrings("ConnectionStringName").ToString())
If you are trying to read custom app settings:
Dim value as String = ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings("keynamehere")
Just kind of depends on what you are trying to read..

Comment: I'm trying to read system.web/sessionState with the GetSectionGroup method.

Comment: Edited the what I'd tried slightly. Basically I just want a Configuration object from parsing the file from disk, which have parsed all web.config-settings correctly.

Comment: I don't know if this will work for you but the web.config file is simply a XML Document.  You could read it in and drill down using root.descendants... I would use the XDocument method.  Hope I'm not leading you down the wrong path.

Comment: yes that is an option, and the best one so far. I was hoping to leverage the methods of WebConfigurationManager, but so far it seems to be impossible from unit tests.

Comment: Perhaps use ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(), considering that your code would have to have some knowledge of the actual path on disk to the web.config file?